# How to assign a directory role to user in Azure AD programmatically

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Is there an API for doing this sort of stuff?

Would also like to invite guests/users to the directory (like you do in the Azure Portal).

I'm thinking to allow this sort of functionality from a WebAPI. ASP.NET Core specifically.

Answer (score 1):

For assigning a directory role to user, you can make use of [Add Directory Role member API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
POST /directoryRoles/{id}/members/$ref
```

You make use of [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) or call the REST API directly to do this.

Comment: In the Permissions table, it says "Application: not supported".. Should I only perform this action on behalf of a user with the right permission?

Comment: that's right.. only delegated permissions are supported for this API, so you need to do it in context of a user (acquire the token to work with this API accordingly)

Comment: Could it be any user, or must the user im performing the action for also have specific permissions to assign roles on other users?

Comment: permissions are required for the user performing the action.. I don't think there's any specific permission required for member who is being added